# NHibernate bug sql generator

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, debugging, orm

i have class named **Group**

i tried to test configuration:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();

cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (Group).Assembly);

new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);
```

when i debug this, im getting following sql:

```
 create table Group (
        ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
       CreatedDate DATETIME null,
       primary key (ID)
    )
```

so like i remember, **Group** key reserved for **Group By**

so why NHibernate does not uses quotes like `Group` for table names?

BTW, I'm using Sql Server 2005 and NHibernate 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a reserved keyword as your object name you should mark it with a DBMS specific sign. For example if you are using SQL Server you should put it in [] and use ` for MySql. 
In this example you should write (assuming that you are using SQL server) :

```
<class name="Group" table="[Group]">
```

Comment: In NHibernate, you can use ` and it will be translated to the appropriate database quoting mechanism.